# How do i get the index of the draggable ui.helper in a sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i had some code of a draggable object which links to a sortable.  The issue is that i want to get the index of the helper in regards to the sortable object.

I was trying `ui.helper.index()` ( and `$("div.tar").index(ui.helper);` ) which gets the index in relation to its siblings, but it didn't seem the indexof ui.helper in the sortable list.

Am i doing something wrong?

here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/y2tGv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the draggable event is causing the sortable events to fire, you would need to have a stop event fire such as:

```
`stop: function(event,ui){ console.log("This is the Index:", $(this).index());}`
```

see the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/y2tGv/1/